# Is varargs array creation lazy?

Tags: java, performance

Consider the following code:

```
void someMethod(Object... varargParam){
    if(someCondition){
        doSomethingWith(varargParam);
    }
}
```

If `someCondition` resolves to `false`, `varargParam` is unused. Will the `Object array` still be created or is this creation postphoned to the first use?

Comment: The array is created at the call sites.

Comment: after inlining the function and some reordering the allocation may disappear at runtime, but that's an optimization done by some JITs, not a guarantee by the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`varargParam` is created when the call happens, also if not used in the method itself.

From [JLS 15.14.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.2):

> If the method being invoked is a variable arity method m, it necessarily has n > 0 formal parameters. The final formal parameter of m necessarily has type T[] for some T, and m is necessarily being invoked with k ≥ 0 actual argument expressions.